# How to prove that $x^2+1 \ge 2x $ for $x>0$?

Tags: inequality

How to prove that $x^2+1 \ge 2x $ for $x>0$?

It seems obvious to me but I don't know exactly how to prove it. Any help would be great.

Comment: Of course there is no need to have $x>0$.

Answer (score 7):

hint: $$ (x-1)^2\geq0$$ for all real $x$

Comment: All real $x$ except for 1.

Comment: Should be greater or equal.